# Trouble getting video stream from Bebop 2 (python, open cv and ffmpeg)

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm currently working with the Bebop 2 drone from parrot and I would like to get the video stream from the bebop and to use the frame I get. To control the bebop I'm using this library : https://github.com/amymcgovern/pyparrot.

First I've tried to use opencv by opening the sdp file used by the bebop to stream the video with this code :

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture('./bebop.sdp')

    while True :
        rt,img = capture.read()
        cv2.imshow("cam",img)
        cv2.waitKey(10)
```

here is the content of the sdp file :

```
c=IN IP4 192.168.42.1
m=video 55004 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

but I got this error

```
[rtp @ 0000020b890b3300] Protocol 'rtp' not on whitelist 'file,crypto'!
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:808)
warning: ./bebop.sdp (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:809)
False
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 331
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "pilotage.py", line 109, in <module>
   _main_(args)
 File "pilotage.py", line 56, in main
   cv2.imshow('drone view',im)
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:331: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

I've seen that this is due to the ffmpeg command used by opencv that does not include the option -protocol_whitelist
So I tried to get the image directly with ffmpeg by using this command

```
"ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist \"file,rtp,udp\"  -i  ./bebop.sdp -r 30 -b:v 800k image_%03d.png &"
```

But the images I got were awful and useless.
Like this one :
[image: bad quality photo]

So I tried different options to improve the quality but I can't get it to work.
Thanks for your help.

I'm on windows 10 and using latest python version

Comment: You can't set this option in OpenCV as mentioned [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10328). As for image quality, check the video stream by: `ffplay -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -i bebop.sdp`

Comment: ffplay is working ! Now I have to find a way to use the video it display

Comment: See [this link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10328). If you're not using the latest version of ffmpeg then you can use a proxy with ffserver.

Comment: Ok I'm trying to figure out how to do this proxy server. This solution looks good tho

Comment: I'm using windows and ffserver only work on linux so I'm gonna try to find something else

Answer (score 0):

I was also working with the Bebop before. I guess it is hard to provide video streaming service on the Bebop. So I have tried to trace the source code to solve this poor quality problem.

I notice that he(amymcgovern) wrote a streaming server by himself and you can see those code in `pyparrot/networking/wifiConnection.py`. But I don't know how to build a better streaming server, I was just looking for options to adjust the server.

I find two options are editable:

The first one is in `pyparrot/Bebop.py`. We can set the stream mode by the function `set_video_stream_video`. It contains three mode: `low_latency`, `high_realiability`, `high_reliability_low_framerate`. I think we can tried to different mode.

The second one is in `pyparrot/DroneVision.py`. It contains an option `self.fps` in `__init__`, and I think we can decrease the frame rate to increase the quality of picture and to reduce the system loading.

BTW, `ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist xxxxxx` would cause `ffmpeg` parse args error, and I think you can comment the part in `pyparrot/DroneVision.py`.(The command string is stored in a variable, called `cmdStr`) I have a similar solution like you, and I just use another program to save those pictures. I use `mplayer` to connect to the streaming and save pictures into jpeg file every second.

```
mplayer -vo jpeg -sstep 1 bebop.sdp
```

Maybe I can connect to the streaming server with `ffmpeg`, but I am tired of reading the document of `ffmpeg`. Anyway, we have another drone now, so I don't spend much time on it.